# Reset EditText's background after custom background

Tags: android, colors, background, android-edittext, reset

How can I reset the default background of an EditText widget after giving it a custom colour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do this for an app I wrote.  In this sample, I check if an `EditText` is empty, and create a `TextWatcher` if it is empty.  Check it out:

```
// highlight any unfilled boxes
final EditText text = (EditText) activity.findViewById(id);
String data = text.getText().toString();
if (data.length() == 0) //
{
    final Drawable oldBackground = activity.findViewById(id).getBackground();
    text.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() //
    {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) //
        {
            text.setBackgroundDrawable(oldBackground);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) 
        {    }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {    }
    });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, that did the job. I used getBackground to get the reference before editing and then set the background to that reference value to reset.